# script dont give result via mail while run though crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I have written a script which ssh to servers and executes the command. Then it mails the output.

The script is running fine manually but in crontab it mails out an empty file.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hello, this is your first question on stackoverflow, welcome. Please improve your question after reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. They are missing information (the command for instance but also a lot of context information), add them to fix please

Answer (score 0):

usaly I do this
run the command

```
bash -x myscript.sh
```

if its runs good i put it on crontab 
crontab -e `crontab -e` and usually its the $PATH issue
lets say in terminal you can write ping www.google.com but in crontab
******/1 /bin/ping www.google.com
or you can check sudo
sodu 
`******/1 sudo /bin/ping www.google.com`
anyway a /var/log/crontab log will give you answer
p.s
take a look at sudoers

Comment: I did it but still the same output